# Как убрать USB Wi-Fi адаптер из "Безопасного извлечения устройств"?

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, устройство

У меня есть проблема - USB Wi-Fi адаптер отображается как извлекаемое устройство в трее, даже не смотря на то, что в проводнике его нет.

[image: Устройство]

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Источник на английском* - https://superuser.com/a/1676269/1774837

### Скрываем устройство

Если вы хотите *скрыть* устройство из "Безопасного извлечения устройств":

> **Прежде чем вы будете что-либо делать**, убедитесь что у вас сделана точка восстановления, или сделана резервная копия параметров реестра, которые вы собираетесь редактировать.
> На всякий случай.

1. Найдите ваш ID устройства в Диспетчере устройств, во вкладке "Сведения", и там выбрать "ИД оборудования".
   **Вам нужна только эта часть - `VID_XXXX&PID_XXXX`.**
   [image: Вкладка "Сведения"]
2. Найдите тот ID в разделе реестра `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\`
   [image: Нужный раздел реестра]
3. Откройте этот раздел и вы найдёте ещё один подраздел, выберите его и вычтете из **шестнадцатеричного** значение `Capabilities` 4.
   К примеру, если там было 0x000000**14**, то должно стать 0x000000**10**.
   [image: Отредактированное значение]

> Если в разделе больше 1 подраздела, то таким же образом вычтите 4 из каждого значение `Capabilities`.

После всего этого, если вы откроете список "Безопасного извлечения устройств", вы должны заметить, что устройства больше нет в списке.

[image: Пустой список]

Это меню останется в трее пока вы не перезагрузите ПК.
**ОДНАКО, изменения, сделанные в разделе реестра `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB`, возвращаются в исходное состояние после перезагрузки.**
Чтобы сделать это изменения постоянным, вам нужно создать задачу в Планировщике задач, чтобы новое значение применялось каждый раз когда вы запускаете ПК.

### Сделать его постоянным

1. У вас всё ещё открыт Редактор реестра?
   **Экспортируйте отредактированные значения** и сохраните их куда-нибудь.

[image: Экспорт]

2. Откройте сохранённый файл раздела реестра, который вы до этого экспортировали, и **удалите всё, кроме значения `Capabilities`.**
   Должно выглядеть примерно вот так (в моём случае):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_0CF3&PID_9271\12345]
"Capabilities"=dword:00000010
```

3. Сохраните его куда-нибудь.
   Я сохранил его по пути `C:\hide\hide.reg`.
4. Откройте Планировщик задач, и создайте **простую задачу**:

- Имя задачи какое хотите.
- Запускать задачу при запуске компьютера.
- Действие - запустить программу.

  - Программа или скрипт: `regedit`
  - Аргументы: `/s "<расположение вашего файла реестра>"`
    (в моём случае получилось `/S "C:\hide\hide.reg"`)
    Эта команда заменит значение(-я) реестра `Capabilities`.

5. Как только вы создали задачу, откройте её свойства и **измените Параметры безопасности**, должно выглядеть вот так:
   [image: Параметры]

- **Выполнять для всех пользователей**

  - **Не сохранять пароль**
- **Выполнить с наивысшими правами**

Теперь, при каждом запуске вашего ПК, прежде чем вы войдёте, эта задача выполнится и скроет ваше устройство из списка "Безопасного извлечения устройств".

Перезагрузите ваш ПК, и тот значок "Безопасного извлечения устройств" должен исчезнуть (если у вас не подключено другое съёмное устройство).

Не беспокойтесь, для других съёмных USB устройств оно будет работать как обычно!

### Но...

Это будет работать до тех пор, пока вы **не отсоедините или поменяете ваше *скрытое* устройство, даже если ваш ПК отключен.**
Если вы это сделаете, то Windows перезарегистрирует то устройство, и оно снова появится в списке "Безопасного извлечения устройств".
Вам нужно будет выполнить все эти шаги заново.